# New Category not showing on News options tab in typo3

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-flow, tx-news

I have created new category but when I want to create news and assign to a particular category that new category does not come in the **available categories list**.

Comment: Please add the TYPO3 version you are using and which extension and which version as tt_news is completly different than news (often seen as tx-news)

Comment: Hi Georg, I am using News system 2.3.0 and in data base table name is like "tx_news_domain_model_category"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the system categories in the form but are creating News categories. When creating the new category look for a second category record type under the "System Records" branch. You should probably also start by looking for the system folder that contains the correct type of categories (if I recall correctly, migrating the categories puts the new categories in the same sysfolder as the old ones).

You may then want to clean out the old News category records - assuming you have run all the necessary migration commands, those tables will no longer be in use.

Comment: Please guide me how to create a system categories and assign them to a news

Comment: I have solved my issue, there is a restriction on Categories for a user in admin users level..I have checked that checkbox and given permissions. Successfully I have seen all categories in News options tab